# IE javascript troubles not firing event

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem with following script,

```
$('#colours li a').click(function(e) {

    $('option').attr("selected", false);

    var selected = $(this).parent("li");
    var colour = selected.attr("class");
    colour = colour.replace("rounded ", "");

  alert(colour);

    $('option[value=' + colour + ']').attr('selected',true);


    if($("#" + colour).hasClass("active")) { return; }

    var active = $(".active");
    var next = $("#" + colour);

    $('#colours li').removeClass("active");
    selected.addClass("active");

    $('option[value=' + colour + ']').attr('selected',true);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Basically what this does is on click it should select a value in a hidden select however in IE8 this is not happening, why is this?

Comment: Have you try replacing .attr("selected",...) by prop()?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to change the selected `option` by just changing the value of the parent `select`.

`$('select').val(colour)` will replace both of the `attr()` calls. Changing the value of a `select` automatically takes care of the `selected` change

`attr()` is not the preferred method for `selected` either, should use `prop()`. This is likely the root of the  problem you are having